# How to substitute a symbol in an expression ? (using sympy)

Tags: python, sympy

I try to use 'subs' function to sobstitute the symbol in a numeric value but dosen't work. Anyone can help me? Thankyou!

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.solvers import solve
import sympy as sym

x = sp.Symbol('x')

s= (3*x + 0)
r= (2*x + 0.8)
eq=r+s
Xbox=sym.solve(eq)
s.subs(x, Xbox)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is a list of values. In this case, the list is of length one, so replace x with the first element of Xbox: `s.subs(x, Xbox[0]) -> -0.480000000000000`